# Gemfire - IllegalStateException on cache create

Tags: java, distributed-caching, distributed-cache

I'm trying to run a Gemfire client app but I'm getting an IllegalStateException when running the following code:

```
//clientPool is the name of the pool from the client
DynamicRegionFactory.Config config = new DynamicRegionFactory.Config(null,(String)"clientPool",false,true);
dynRegFact = DynamicRegionFactory.get();
dynRegFact.open(config);        
_cache = new ClientCacheFactory().set("locators", "")
                .set("mcast-port", "0").set("log-level", "error")
                .set("cache-xml-file", xmlFileName)
                .create();
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The client pool of a DynamicRegionFactory must be configured with queue-enabled set to true.

I can't figure out how to set the queue-enabled to true. I would appreciate some code, not answers like "check this part of the documentation". I've already looked everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable subscription in your pool. Just add *subscription-enabled="true"* attribute to your pool configuration.

Note: Your client should support transactions. It's better to use dynamic regions on cache servers. From client call remote function.

Example:

Function:

```
public class CreateRegionFunction extends FunctionAdapter {

@Override
public void execute(FunctionContext fc) {
    String name = (String) fc.getArguments();
    Region reg = DynamicRegionFactory.get().createDynamicRegion("/parent",
            name);

    if (reg == null) {
        fc.getResultSender().lastResult("ERROR");
    } else {
        fc.getResultSender().lastResult("DONE");
    }
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return "create-region-function";
}

}
```

Server side:

```
CreateRegionFunction creatRegFun = new CreateRegionFunction(); 
FunctionService.registerFunction(creatRegFun);
```

Add dynamic-region-factory in your server cache:

```
<dynamic-region-factory />
```

Client side:

```
FunctionService.onServer(PoolManager.find("poolName"))
     .withArgs("child")
     .execute("create-region-function")
     .getResult();
```

In this case it's not obligatory to use DynamicRegionFactory, you can use RegionFactory and create root regions.

Comment: Didn't work, I get an exception creating the cache - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: operation is not supported on a client cache - it's thrown before the other exception.

Comment: How do I support transactions from the client?

Comment: Transactions on the client will be supported in GemFire 6.6. Now you should create function if you want to have transaction.